# Adding a background image and background color pair to elements

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, background-color

I'm trying to add a pair of background styles to the `html` tag in a specific way. Here's what I have so far.

```
$(function() {
  var images = ['bg-day.png', 'bg-sunset.png', 'bg-night'];
  var colors = ['#0066CD', '#ff0000', '#1D2951'];
  $('html').css({'background-image': 'url(img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
});
```

So, what I need to do is pair the variables correspondingly, where the 0 position is both `bg-day.png` and `#0066CD`, and so on. Thus, if the background image that is served to the `html` tag is `bg-day.png`, it'll add a background color of `#0066CD` to the `html` tag as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the random number, and use it as an index for both arrays:

```
$(function() {
  var images = ['bg-day.png', 'bg-sunset.png', 'bg-night'],
      colors = ['#0066CD', '#ff0000', '#1D2951'],
      index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

  $('html').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/' + images[index] + ')',
                 'background-color' : colors[index]
               });
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. First, with your solution I had to change `background-image` to `background` since you're using the shorthand method. But, for some reason, after fixing that, it is giving me inconsistent results, often when I reload there's no background information at all attached to the `html` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work inconsistently like that, but the concept of using the same index for both arrays should work just fine. I did'nt think about setting the color and url would require the shorthand version, as that's what I always use anyway, but you could try setting both seperately.

Comment: Perfect. Sweet, your updated version is working as intended. Thanks!